# Conjugation of modal verb "would."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The nuns taught me that shall/will is conjugated this way:

> I shall
> you will
> he will
> we shall
> you will
> they will

Similarly, should/would is conjugated this way:

> I should
> you would
> he would
> we should
> you would
> they would

My specific question was, how long ago was I shall / we shall and I should / we should replaced by I will / we will and I would / we would in the popular vernacular?

Had I got it wrong back in the fourth grade, I could have expected my knuckles to get rapped

I've deleted the editorializing comment I made (apologies).  Now all I want is to get a timeline for when the accepted usage changed.

Comment: Related and probable duplicates: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3),
[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19438),
[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480627),
[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/476984),
[5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/324084)...

Comment: It's not "correct" usage, so there's nothing to decry. It's a pattern that was only ever used by a slim minority of native speakers, mostly Oxbridgians living in the south of England a long time ago.

Comment: The suggestions in the post are total nonsense. _Would_ and _should_ are two different verbs; they are not inflected versions of one another, and they never have been. From a false premise any conclusion at all may be drawn.

Comment: I disagree with the "nonsense" comment.  Whatever you label it, the conjugation I provided was in fact correct.  We are not talking about two different verbs.

Comment: It's not that it changed as the proponents of the view you learned in grade school have all died out. There never was a speech community that followed those rules; they were dreamed up by country parsons with classical educations and too much time on their hands, who felt that The Poor would do better if they talked more like their Betters did, or at least like the parsons thought the Betters would speak if they tried hard enough. Basically they were Influencers, as we call such people today. I learned this stuff too, but I never heard anybody talk that way.

Comment: Well, I was taught that 'I shall' is a prediction, 'I will' expresses resolution (as used in the traditional C of E marriage service), and for some reason it's the other way round for _you_ ('Cinderella, you _shall_ go to the ball.')

Comment: As far as the history of _would_ and _should_ is concerned, there used to be English modal verbs that were inflected for tense. _Will_ (actually _willan_ in OE) was one and it had a past tense _would_; _shall_ was another and it had a past tense _should_. But now they are just four of the 9 English modal auxiliaries and don't inflect for tense any more. Nor have they ever commuted with one another in the manner you describe (btw, the original zombie source says that to emphasize, one reverses the pattern -- another thing I've never witnessed).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138348/discussion-on-question-by-t-bell-shall-will-should-would).

Comment: @JohnLawler This is a great question (though probably asked a hundred times before) . Why are questions about form (or history, or lack of history, or made up history) closed as opinion? The OP is not asking for whether things should happen this way or what is best. Just for information. That is entirely on topic. If you know something about the history, that's part of a good answer. If not much is known about the history, the range of dates where the change happened, that's simply lack of knowledge, not opinion.

Comment: @Mitch When they're full of false presuppositions and vague ideas that have to be corrected before even beginning to answer the question, for starts. I don't think it's "great" at all. And why ask it again if they didn't get it the first hundred times?

Comment: @JohnLawler You may not have witnessed it, but I certainly have on my [eastern] side of the Atlantic. I was taught the forms in the question at school too, in the Seventies/early Eighties.

Comment: I'm neither knowledgeable about nor responsible for how English is or was taught anywhere in the UK. I had a US Catholic education, to which I refer.

Comment: [Fowler in 1908](https://www.bartleby.com/116/213.html) struggled to explain the usage of *shall* and *will*, suggesting the existence of 3 systems and 7 rules governing their use. "Rule 2. The Coloured-Future System" appears to match the OP's contours. I've struggled and failed to summarise or indeed understand Fowler's remarks. Perhaps someone else could attempt it. Regardless, an excellent rule in life is to ignore anything a nun tells you.

Comment: @JohnLawler How do you reconcile 'There never was a speech community that followed those rules…' with 'they were dreamed up by country parsons with (anywhat)'? Right or wrong, how did the country parsons not themselves constitute a speech community?

Comment: @JohnLawler. Where does 'Would and should are different verbs…' come from, please. How is either 'would' or 'should' a verb?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you don't know why _would_ or _should_ are verbs, I'm not going to tell you. You could look up "modal auxiliary verbs" if you remain puzzled.

Comment: @JohnLawler I see what you mean, and I suggest far fewer than one in ten native speakers of English would understand that. They might all accept is a gospel, and that doesn't mean they'd understand it. Think not about your qualified or experiences colleagues, but your own secondary-school class-mates. If my view makes sense only by suggesting that the classification 'modal auxiliary verb' should be reduced in status, so be it. Again how did the country parsons not themselves constitute a speech community? Were they not thousands strong, and much better educated than most?

Comment: Modal auxiliary verbs are auxiliary verbs; and auxiliary verbs are verbs. Q.E.D. Country parsons can take care of themselves.

Comment: By the way, verbs that are not inflected (like modal auxiliary verbs) do not have any conjugations. _Conjugation_ is the Latin term for verbal inflection, usually arranged in a paradigm chart. No inflections, no conjugations.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that it changed, as the proponents of the view you learned in grade school have all died out. There never was a speech community that followed those rules; they were dreamed up by country parsons with classical educations and too much time on their hands, who felt that The Poor would do better if they talked more like their Betters did, or at least like the parsons thought the Betters would speak if they tried hard enough. Basically they were Influencers, as we call such people today. I learned this stuff in school too, but I never heard anybody talk that way. [JL]

...

As far as the history of *would* and *should* is concerned, there used to be English modal verbs that were inflected for tense. *Will* (actually *willan* in OE) was one, and it had a past tense *would*; *shall* was another and it had a past tense *should*. But now they are just four of the 9 English modal auxiliaries and don't inflect for tense any more. Nor have they ever commuted with one another in the manner you describe (btw, the original zombie source says that to emphasize, one reverses the pattern -- another thing I've never witnessed). [John Lawler]

.......

Fowler in 1908 struggled to explain the usage of *shall* and *will*, suggesting the existence of 3 systems and 7 rules governing their use. "Rule 2. The Coloured-Future System" appears to match the OP's contours. I've struggled and failed to summarise or indeed understand Fowler's remarks. Perhaps someone else could attempt it. Regardless, an excellent rule in life is to ignore anything a [*non-expert] tells you. [Stuart F] [*sanitised]

Comment: While it is helpful that some of the comments are now protected from deletion by having been incorporated into this wiki-answer, it should be noted that, as has been pointed out by other commentators above, they do not really answer the question. Granting, for the sake of argument, that this approach to *shall/will* was, by some criteria, misguided, it still remains a historical fact that millions of people were taught something like that, that they were, at least somewhat, influenced by it, and that almost nobody is affected by it any more. It is reasonable to ask when that change occurred.

Comment: I selected what I considered the most useful commentary. I myself came across the wsswss for future and swwsww for emphasis, with also wwwwww for expression of a wish, advice over 50 years ago, and seem to remember the teacher saying it was outdated even then, and better ditched. John Lawler is the only authority I've seen address this.

Comment: @jsw29 The questions asks about when the change ocurred "in the popular vernacular", and JL says that the distinction never actually existed in the popular vernacular. ("There never was a speech community that followed those rules") I therefore think that this does, technically, answer the question.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, saying that the rules were never followed 'in the popular vernacular' is something different from saying that 'there never was a speech community that followed those rules'. The former claim is difficult to evaluate due to the vagueness of *popular vernacular*, but the latter seems false, even according to Professor Lawler (who admits, in the same comment, that the 'country parsons' followed these rules, and that they were influencers, which implies that they influenced somebody) and tchrist (who says they were followed by 'Oxbridgians living in the south of England').

Comment: @jsw29 I think that if "there never was a speech community that followed those rules," then that would rule out the possibility that they were ever followed "in the popular vernacular". I don't find "popular vernacular" to be very vague, but perhaps I understand it differently than you do.

Comment: @jsw29 I don't find JL's statements contradictory. I think that he's claiming that the country parsons taught those rules to students but didn't actually follow the rules themselves when speaking. At least that's my understanding; perhaps he could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I used [adde](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20shall%2FI%20will&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).  "I shall" was never more common than "I will" (at least, back to 1800). In 1800, they were about equal. "I shall" gradually declined, now it is about 1/4 as common as "I will".

As for "should" and "would", I think your nuns were just wrong. "I should" and "I would" are both fine, but they mean different things.

Comment: You should include a link to the Ngram that you used, so that other's might view the results from the same query.

Comment: I had tried to link the image. That didn't work. So, now, I've put in the link.

Comment: And doubtless << I'll >>, which neatly dodges the argument over which of will/shall should be used where, eclipses both.